# Email client doesn't work in elementary OS

Tags: pantheon-mail

I've tried to configure my gmail account on elementary OS through the email client, but I didn't succeed. The app always says the password or email is wrong.
Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things you need to do in order to get gmail working in Mail.

Check here for the [solution](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13569/email-client-gmail)